# casting value emitted from qml on drag drop

Tags: qt5, qt-quick, qtquick2

In my QML:

```
DropArea {
  onDropped: {
    root.dropSignal(drop);
  }
}
```

With the signal defined as:

```
signal dropSignal(var data)
```

My slot function:

```
void MainSlot::dropSlot(const QVariant &data)
{
  qDebug() << "Called the C++ slot with data:" << data;
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
Called the C++ slot with data: QVariant(QObject*, QQuickDropEvent(0x7fff5fbfd828) )
```

I need help casting this object to what I would expect is a Drop event of some kind. I want the C++ code to handle the logic of accepting/rejecting the drop and accessing the data from the drop.

I can't find QQuickDropEvent in the class reference. I did find QDropEvent. From the documentation on DragArea, it is not clear what is the C++ equivalent to the QML DragEvent or in which header file DragEvent is defined in.

Trying a cast like this has not worked:

```
QDropEvent *item = qobject_cast<QDropEvent*>(v.value<QObject*>());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QML's `DragEvent` = `QQuickDropEvent`

This is stated in this updated version of the [QML DragEvent documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-dragevent.html) fresh from the [sources](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/751fa46df9bf06a1003df34b3e74c73c079e8626%3asrc/quick/items/qquickdroparea.cpp)

```
/*!
    \qmltype DragEvent
    \instantiates QQuickDropEvent
    \inqmlmodule QtQuick
    \ingroup qtquick-input-events
    \brief Provides information about a drag event

    The position of the drag event can be obtained from the \l x and \l y
    properties, and the \l keys property identifies the drag keys of the event
    \l source.

    The existence of specific drag types can be determined using the \l hasColor,
    \l hasHtml, \l hasText, and \l hasUrls properties.

    The list of all supplied formats can be determined using the \l formats property.

    Specific drag types can be obtained using the \l colorData, \l html, \l text,
    and \l urls properties.

    A string version of any available mimeType can be obtained using \l getDataAsString.
*/
```

`QQuickDropEvent`'s header is available in [src/quick/items/qquickdroparea_p.h](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/751fa46df9bf06a1003df34b3e74c73c079e8626%3asrc/quick/items/qquickdroparea_p.h). I guess this is a private header file again, which means you are not supposed to handle these events in C++ but in Javascript.

A `QQuickDropEvent` instance contains a private instance variable of type `QDropEvent` that you can not access directly.

**Edit:** You might want to copy the drop's properties in Javascript and pass an array to C++ (untested):

```
DropArea {
    var actionIdToString = function(id) {
        if (id ===   Qt.CopyAction) return 'Qt.CopyAction';
        if (id ===   Qt.MoveAction) return 'Qt.MoveAction';
        if (id ===   Qt.LinkAction) return 'Qt.LinkAction';
        if (id === Qt.IgnoreAction) return 'Qt.IgnoreAction';
        return 'Unexpected action';
    }

    onDropped: {
        var dropProperties = [
            drop.accepted,
            actionIdToString(drop.action),
            drop.drag.source,
            drop.keys,
            drop.supportedActions,
            drop.x,
            drop.y
        ]
        root.dropSignal(dropProperties);
    }
}
```

There is a blog post about [passing more complex datastructures between C++ and QML](http://ruedigergad.com/2011/11/13/exchange-data-and-objects-between-c-and-qml-and-vice-versa/). As far as I can see, you will get a `QVariantList` when passing a Javascript array to your slot.

You might want to consider using a Javascript object ([JSON style](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qml-var.html)) in order to access the drop's properties by name instead of index in C++, but I am not sure how well objects survive the step from QML to C++.

Comment: So does this mean I should embed a C++ object into the context to provide the logic for the event handler?

[http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html]

Comment: I added a section on how you can copy not the drop but its properties to C++. Does that help?

Comment: That is indeed very kind of you to write that example.

However, there is one issue with it: it prevents me from delegating responsibility to calling drop.accept() to a C++ class.

In your example, I am passing drop.accepted, and that value will depend on whether I decide to call drop.accept() in the qml and that does not seem ideal.

To be honest, it seems weird that my C++ cannot attach a SLOT directly to the onDropped event...seems like a SIGNAL should already exist for every event that is dispatched within qml.

Comment: While we're talking about it, where is the method on DragEvent to access the data given a provided key...for example in html5: e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');

Comment: Far from ideal, that's right. But since Qt's interface is as it is for the time being, there are only two possibilities: process drop in Javascript or deal with private headers. You already showed that your slot works and that you receive the data in C++. Now you can cast the QVariant to QQuickDropEvent and work with it. You have to find the headers, include them, find the function names etc. in the Qt source code because there is no documentation.